# Pre load true type fonts

Tags: wordpress, fonts, preload, pagespeed-insights

Google page insights recommended pre loading a fonts file.  I have tried all four of the following code snippets in my   but still cannot get it to pre load.  Many thanks in advance for any help :-)

> https://www.ways-to-make-money.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf” as=”font” type="font/x-generic" crossorigin >
>
> https://www.ways-to-make-money.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf” as=”font” type="font/x-generic" >
>
> https://www.ways-to-make-money.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf” as=”font” type="font/ttf >
>
> https://www.ways-to-make-money.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf” as=”font” type="font/ttf crossorigin >

Comment: small note here: [don't use .ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373751/pre-load-true-type-fonts).

Comment: Thank Mike. How do I do this? Can I just delete the modules.ttf file?

Comment: Just write your CSS to declare an `@font-face` rule that only uses woff/woff2 sources, and the in your HTML source, preload those same woff/woff2 sources using `<link rel="prefetch" href="url to those woff/woff2 source files - one link element per file">` _before_ you load your CSS.